# this.setState not re-rendering view ReactJS and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, setstate

I have a rails app with two reactJS components (not parent/child) that are currently communicating through a global events Pub/Sub system.

However when I run `this.setState({ items: this.props.items })` I am getting the message `Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`.

Any help people can offer on why I might be getting this error would be much appreciated.

The basic setup I have is:

**BasketContainer - subscribed to two events**

```
class BasketContainer extends React.Component{

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        subTotal: 0,
        totalPrice: 0,
        deliveryPrice: 0
    }
}
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState( {
        items: this.props.items,
    })
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.token = PubSub.subscribe('ADD_BASKET', this.handleUpdate)
    this.token = PubSub.subscribe('REMOVE_ITEM', this.handleUpdate)
    this.calculateTotals();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
PubSub.unsubscribe(this.token)
}

handleUpdate(msg, data){
    console.log(msg)
    this.setState({
        items:this.props.items // ERROR MESSAGE - Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
    })
}
.... Rest of file
```

**ProductItem - Add to Basket Event Publisher**

```
class ProductItem extends React.Component{

constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = { 
        name: '',
        price: 0,
        code: '',
        id: ''
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        name: this.props.data.name,
        price: this.props.data.price,
        code: this.props.data.code,
        id: this.props.data.id
    })
}

addtoBasket() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/items",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            item: {
                name: this.state.name,
                price: this.state.price,
                code: this.state.code
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            PubSub.publish('ADD_BASKET', data); // THIS WORKS FINE
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}

render(){
    let productName = this.props.data.name
    let productPrice = this.props.data.price
    let productCode = this.props.data.code
    let productImg = this.props.data.image_url

    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 product">
            <img src={productImg}/>
            <h3 className="text-center">{productName}</h3>
            <h5 className="text-center">£{productPrice}</h5>
            <div className="text-center">
                <button onClick={this.addtoBasket.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**BasketItem - Remove from Basket Publisher**

```
class BasketItem extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super()

    this.state = { 
        name: '',
        price: 0,
        code: '',
        id: '',
        quantity: 1,
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        name: this.props.data.name,
        price: this.props.data.price,
        code: this.props.data.code,
        id: this.props.data.id,
    })
}

deleteItem() {
    let finalUrl = '/items/' + this.state.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: finalUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            PubSub.publish('REMOVE_ITEM', data); // THIS WORKS FINE
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}   

render(){
    let itemName = this.props.data.name
    let itemCode = this.props.data.code
    let itemQuantity = 1
    let itemPrice = (this.props.data.price * itemQuantity).toFixed(2)
    const itemId = this.props.data.id

    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{itemName}</td>
            <td>{itemCode}</td>
            <td>{itemQuantity}</td>
            <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}>Remove</button></td>
            <td>£{itemPrice}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with following line of code

```
this.token = PubSub.subscribe('ADD_BASKET', this.handleUpdate)
```

The function you are passing as param needs to be binded with 'this'

```
this.token = PubSub.subscribe('ADD_BASKET', this.handleUpdate.bind(this))
```

Same for REMOVE_ITEM action. Then should be good to go :)

Comment: Thanks for your help - that's got rid of the error but setState doesn't seem to be re-rendering the Component, any idea why this might be? :)

Comment: In BasketContainer, componentWillMount() you are setting state with this.props.items, in handleUpdate() you are doing same. So, state is not changing there.

Comment: componentWillMount is called before the render method is executed. It is important to note that setting the state in this phase will not trigger a re-rendering. In handleUpdate(), you need to manipulate this.state.items according to the 'data' param and then set state accordingly.

Comment: Hey, I've used this.state.items.push(data); to push the data before calling setState which is working great. What would I do in an instance where I am removing an item from the items array? Thanks so much for all your help

Comment: For that, you need to remove that 'data' from this.state.items array. I assume param 'data' must have any unique property i.e. 'id' or 'code'. So, you can do something like, let newStateItems = this.state.items.filter((i) => i.id != data.id); this.setState({items:newStateItems});

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass property `items` to **BasketContainer** from its parent class. That's why you are getting error `Cannot read property 'items' of undefined.`

Update: the line where you have mentioned the error, the error you are getting is because of wrong reference of `this`;

try something like:

```
handleUpdate(msg, data){
    var self = this;
    this.setState({
        items: self.props.items // Here get props from self variable
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. BasketContainer doesn't have a parent class though which is why I am using the Pub/Sub events system. Rohit's comment below has got rid of the error but now setState isn't re-rendering. Any idea why this might be?